# Qt Open Source licensing

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use Qt LGPL license and sell my application without any kind of restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994053/can-i-use-qt-lgpl-license-and-sell-my-application-without-any-kind-of-restrictio)

Just a simple question.

Without the Qt Commercial license, can I make an application and 'sell' it to a client? Or do I need a commercial license to sell it?

Comment: Probably yes, at least if you are linking dynamically your application. But it is the wrong place to ask. BTW, making your application free software may give it a lot more success (and you may have issues in selling your software thru licenses anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as you accept [LGPL 2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) license.