# How to compile C++ with C++11 support in Mac Terminal

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, terminal, g++

I wanted to compile C++11 source code within Mac Terminal but failed. I tried `g++ -std=c++11`, `g++ -std=c++0x`, `g++ -std=gnu++11` and `g++ -std=gnu++0x` but nothing worked. Terminal always read `unrecognized command line option`. However, `g++ -std=gnu` and things like that worked fine (of course C++11 source code could not pass).

Which option should I use to turn on C++11 support?

By the way, the command line tool I'm using is installed within Xcode, and I'm pretty sure that they are up-to-date.

Comment: GCC that comes with Xcode is **not** up-to-date, in fact it's ancient. Try `clang++`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Cool, worked perfectly. Thanks. However, `clang++` warned me of C++11 features... Any options to turn those warnings off?

Comment: Use the `-w` option to turn off all warnings.

Comment: The debugger to use is lldb

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As others have pointed out you should use `clang++` rather than `g++`. Also, you should use the libc++ library instead of the default libstdc++; The included version of libstdc++ is quite old and therefore does not include C++11 library features.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything main.cpp
```

If you haven't installed the command line tools for Xcode you can run the compiler and other tools without doing that by using the `xcrun` tool.

```
xcrun clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything main.cpp
```

Also if there's a particular warning you want to disable you can pass additional flags to the compiler to do so. At the end of the warning messages it shows you the most specific flag that would enable the warning. To disable that warning you prepend `no-` to the warning name.

For example you probably don't want the c++98 compatibility warnings. At the end of those warnings it shows the flag `-Wc++98-compat` and to disable them you pass `-Wno-c++98-compat`.

Comment: Just tested what you said. Indeed, a simple `std::array` knocks default `libstdc++` out.

Comment: Yes had a problem with compiling `std::is_heap()` without `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: I also had to: -mmacosx-version-min=10.7

Answer (score 28):

XCode uses `clang` and `clang++` when compiling, not `g++` (assuming you haven't customized things). Instead, try:

```
$ cat t.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ t.cpp
$ ./a.out 
0x0
```

Thanks to bames53's answer for pointing out that I had left out `-stdlib=libc++`.

If you want to use some GNU extensions (and also use C++11), you can use `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=c++11`, which will turn on C++11 mode and also keep GNU extensions enabled.

Comment: Not sure what the -1 was for... If it's because I left out `-stdlib=c++` it would've been nice to have a comment so I could fix it faster!