# Compiler not compiling the following line (C++)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'm having problems trying to compile this code:

```
int *array_aleatorio = new int[8]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

This is the error that shows up:

> main.cpp:315:38: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
>       int *array_aleatorio = new int[8]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

One of my teammates told me this can be because I'm not using the correct compilator. He's using `C++11` and it works. I've tried to install it without any success.

I'm using `OSX 10.6.8` and `Netbeans 7.3`

I'm using `clang++`.
[image]

I've tried this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228856/how-to-compile-c-with-c11-support-in-mac-terminal) solution by adding the `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything` line to the compiling properties of the project, but it's not working:
[image]

This is the error that shows up when I try to execute it by adding the lines above.

> clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything   -c -g -std=c++11
>   -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o
>   main.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation:
>   '-std=c++11' clang: warning: argument unused during compilation:
>   '-stdlib=libc++' warning: unknown warning option '-Weverything'
>   [-Wunknown-warning-option] warning: unknown warning option
>   '-Weverything' [-Wunknown-warning-option] error: invalid value 'c++11'
>   in '-std=c++11'

Can someone tell me how to install C++11 in OSX? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clang supports c++11 just fine.  What version do you have?

Comment: `int array_aleatorio[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};`

Comment: I agree. `new` is looking completely pointless here.

Answer (score 5):

Your Xcode is *way* out of date.  Xcode 3.2.6 was released in *2011* and includes:

```
Apple clang version 1.7 (tags/Apple/clang-77) (based on LLVM 2.9svn)
```

Based on the release date, it's not really surprising that it doesn't have C++11 support.

You want to get Xcode 4.6 which includes:

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
```

You might need to update your OS, too - 10.6.8 is a couple of years old, too.

Comment: I cant update Xcode because as you said, it needs a newer OSX version, and for several reasons, it's impossible to do that.

Comment: Impossible?  Why?  Anyway, you can go get the clang sources and build your own if you're really stuck.

Comment: Due to some HD redimensions if I want to update the OSX I've to do it by clean installation instead of updating the OSX normally. And for that I need to backup all the data and I don't have the time to do that now. I'll try to do what you're saying.

Comment: 1. You should probably be backing up regularly. 2. Why can't you install the new OS on an external drive then?

Comment: I was simply looking for a solution that avoids any OS update.

Comment: @Borja I am currently testing the use of the open source MacPorts on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 to obtain the clang++ 3.3 compiler.  I have a slow (by today's high speed expectations) Internet connection.  It has been about 2 hours downloading the files and installing normally.  When it is all complete and running properly, I will post an answer with the details.  Hopefully this is not too late to be useful.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD Nevermind. I had to change all my code to `Python` so don't worry. Anyways, thanks for the interest.

Comment: @Borja Well, if you would like to review the MacPorts usage details, check out my answer posted for [Problems throwing and catching exceptions on OS X with -fno-rtti](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737201/problems-throwing-and-catching-exceptions-on-os-x-with-fno-rtti/22135849#comment33612941_22135849).  My post starts with the words: *Start Edit March 4, 2014*

Answer (score 1):

The last supported version(that comes with xcode) of clang on snow leopard is not c++11 compatible, but you can install macports ( http://www.macports.org/install.php ) and with the help of the console you can install a newer version of clang, "**sudo port install clang-3.2**" for example.

The folder in which clang is installed can be found with "**whereis clang-3.2**"